# .htaccess file doesn't exist

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am beginner in web development. I launched website from hostgator. in my index.php I used phpmailer but when I click send button "HTTP ERROR 500" appears. I think it happens because I don't have .htaccess file. I am searching now but can't find .htaccess example to add to my project. can somebody show me an example of .htaccess? and also tell me where to add it - homepage or my website project directory where index.php exists?

in my index.php file I started from bootstrap template and modified by myself. purpose of .htaccess file is to send emails with phpmailer. here is my index.php document:

```
    <?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exceptions;

require 'phpmailer/src/Exceptions.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

if(isset($_POST["send"])){
  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = 'info@mil-data.com';
  $mail->Password = 'dgqncmczasdygmwjwbr';
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
  $mail->Port = 465;

  $mail->setForm('info@mil-data.com')

  $mail->addAddress($_POST["email"]);

  $mail->isHTML(true);

  $mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];
  $mail->Body = $_POST["message"];

  $mail->send();

  echo
  "
  <script>
  alert('Sent Successfully');
  document.location.href = 'index.php'
  </script>
  ";
}
```

Comment: The question you asked cannot be answered as we do not know your setting. Please add more information like: what kind of website do you want to host?, is your index.php done by you?, what is the purpose of the .htaccess file? - So basically just for running any simple html website you do not need a .htaccess file.

Comment: Maybe you can also post the content of your index.php

Comment: I added information

Comment: _"I think it happens because I don't have .htaccess file."_ - why, what makes you think that was related to the error? _"can somebody show me an example of .htaccess?"_ - that question makes very little sense - .htaccess is a file containing configuration for the web server. We can not possibly know _what_ configuration your project might need.

Comment: You should first of all go and check what the error log has to say about the _reason_ for this 500 error you are getting.

Comment: _"purpose of .htaccess file is to send emails with phpmailer. "_ no, it is not. That is not what a .htaccess file does. _"in my index.php I used phpmailer"_ - no, you didn't. No phpmailer use anywhere in that code you have shown us above. _"but when I click send button "HTTP ERROR 500" appears."_ - so that means the error actually happens inside your `send.php`.

Comment: The `index.php` is useless, when `send.php` is the problem. Besides, please refrain from requests for tutorials, examples, libraries and random files. This all is being considered as off-topic.

Comment: @sabatananashvili thank you for posting the index.php. But according to that all the mail stuff happens in the mail.php. So please delete the index.php stuff here and post the mail.php content to your question.

Comment: I think it happens because I don't have .htaccess file because I did research and drew that conclusion

Comment: Seems that you have a double form inside your index.php. So please delete the wrong one and then post the correct file content (mail.php or send.php)

Comment: @KlausF. I added send.php

Comment: @sabatananashvili your conclusion is just wrong. HTTP 500 means you have a syntax error, with error reporting disabled... try setting `error_reporting(-1);` on top of that file.

Comment: top of send.php?

Comment: Yes. While I think you first have to `require` and then can `use`.

Comment: @sabatananashvili your file is quite simple. There is no need here for any .htaccess file as far as I can tell from this content. So your problem is either a syntax error somewhere (see comment from Martin Zeitler) or a problem connecting to Google.

Comment: I have done changes Martin told me, but still nothing changes

Comment: Typo and missing `;` in: `$mail->setForm('info@mil-data.com')`. That should be `$mail->setFrom('info@mil-data.com');` Error reporting should have told you that

Comment: now output changed, when I click send button, first line of send.php file appears: error_reporting(-1);

Comment: `error_reporting(-1);` should _not_ be the first line, `<?php` should be

Comment: now that I changed that, error 500 appears again, you can check it yourself - https://hebe.com.ge/

Comment: "_you can check it yourself_" That wouldn't help anyone. We'd see a 500 server error message. _You_ on the other hand have access to the server/error log. Take a look at it, see what caused the 500 and fix it

Comment: It seems that the issue is not directly in the post section of your file - assuming you fixed all typos - maybe the error comes already with the loading of the phpmailer libraries. You can try to comment out all the require lines and then add them one by one.

Comment: when I comment some lines error doesn't appear any more, it tells me message sent successfully and returns me to main page, theese lines are : 1. require 'phpmailer/src/Exceptions.php'; 2. $mail->setForm('info@mil-data.com'); 3. $mail->addAddress($_POST["email"]); 4.$mail->send();

Comment: Don't redirect when you're debugging, temporarily remove the code that redirects. `$mail->setForm('info@mil-data.com');` is _still_ wrong, looks like you didn't fix that typo.

Comment: I fix that, added ; at endline

Comment: @brombeer according to my commented lines, can't you tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can read this article, there it shows an htaccess and also explains a bit of its operation, and you can also check this htaccess generator: https://julianpoemp.github.io/ngx-htaccess-generator/#/generator

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).